# JSF a4j:Repeat doesnot bind the values to backing bean for dynamically generated rows

Tags: jsf, dynamic, jsf-2, row, addition

I have a drop down menu which will add new row of input fields as follows:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="selBillingSelect" rendered="#participantController.enableMultipleBilling}"                                         title="#{awbInformationorderBundle.RATING_DETAILS_ADD_LBL_TIP}"                                         tabindex="#{headerBean.tabIndex}" styleClass="optional"                                         value="#{participantController.numberOfRows}" accesskey="6"                                         style="vertical-align:bottom">
<f:ajax event="change" listener="#{participantController.addBillingLines}"                                              render=":frmParticipantInfo:billingTable hidBillingSize"                                                execute=":frmParticipantInfo:billingTable"                                              onevent="billingAutoExpansion" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Add a Carrier" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="1" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="2" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="3" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="4" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

backing bean code to add data

```
public void addBillingLines(){
    BillingPartsInfoDto aBillingPartsInfoDto = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        if(this.getBillingSize()<this.getMaxAirlineCodeAllowed()){
            aBillingPartsInfoDto= new BillingPartsInfoDto();
            billingInfoDtos.add(aBillingPartsInfoDto);
            this.setBillingSize(this.getBillingInfoDtos().size());
        }
    }
    this.setNumberOfRows(0);
    return;
}
```

i have a a4j:repeat to display the data as follows:

```
    <h:panelGroup id="billingTable"></h:panelGroup>

<a4j:repeat id="billingLines#{rowIndex}" var="item" keepSaved="true" value="#{participantController.billingInfoDtos}" rowKeyVar="rowIndex">                                             <cc:customTable id="billingTable">                                              <cc:customTr styleClass="fieldTitle">                                                   <cc:customTd valign="center">                                                       <h:outputText   value="Carrier Code"                                                    escape="false" />                                                   </cc:customTd>                                                  <cc:customTd valign="center">                                                       <h:outputText                                                       value="#{participantBundle.BILLING_INVOICE_MEDIA_LBL}"                                                          escape="false" />                                                   </cc:customTd>                                                  <cc:customTd><h:outputText styleClass="spacer20" />                                                 </cc:customTd><cc:customTd valign="center">                                                 <h:outputText value="#participantBundle.BILLING_INVOICE_FREQUENCY_LBL}"                                                         escape="false" /></cc:customTd><cc:customTd><h:outputText tyleClass="spacer20" />

                                                    <cc:customTd valign="center">
                                                        <h:outputText value="#{participantBundle.BILLING_INVOICE_SEQUENCE_LBL}"                                                         escape="false" /></cc:customTd>
                                                    <cc:customTd>
                                                        <h:outputText styleClass="spacer20" />
                                                    </cc:customTd>

                                                    <cc:customTd valign="center">
                                                        <h:outputText
                                                            value="#{participantBundle.BILLING_INVOICE_LANGUAGE_LBL}"
                                                            escape="false" />
                                                    </cc:customTd>
                                                    <cc:customTd>
                                                        <h:outputText styleClass="spacer20" />
                                                    </cc:customTd>
                                                    <cc:customTd valign="center">
                                                        <h:outputText
                                                            value="#{participantBundle.BILLING_INVOICE_SITE_LBL}"
                                                            escape="false" />
                                                    </cc:customTd>
                                                    <cc:customTd>
                                                        <h:outputText styleClass="spacer20" />
                                                    </cc:customTd>
                                                    <cc:customTd valign="center">
                                                        <h:outputText
                                                            value="#{participantBundle.BILLING_CURRENCY_LBL}"
                                                            escape="false" />
                                                    </cc:customTd>
                                                    <cc:customTd>
                                                        <h:outputText styleClass="spacer20" />
                                                    </cc:customTd>
                                                    <cc:customTd>
                                                        <h:outputText style="vertical-align:top;"
                                                            value="#{participantBundle.DETAILS_INVOICE_EMAIL_LBL}" />
                                                    </cc:customTd>
                                                </cc:customTr>

                                                <cc:customTr>
                                                    <cc:customTd valign="top">
                                                        <h:selectOneMenu id="carrierCode" value="#{item.airline}"
                                                        title="#{participantBundle.INVOICE_MEDIA_TIP}" rendered="#{participantController.enableMultipleBilling}"
                                                            tabindex="#{headerBean.tabIndex}" style="width:50px;"
                                                            accesskey="#{participantBundle.BILLING_INVOICE_MEDIA_AKEY}"
                                                            styleClass="required">
                                                            <f:selectItems value="#{participantController.specificAirlines}"></f:selectItems>
                                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                                                    </cc:customTd>
                                                    <cc:customTd>
                                                        <h:selectOneMenu id="invoiceMedia1"
                                                            value="#{item.invoiceMedia}"
                                                            title="#{participantBundle.INVOICE_MEDIA_TIP}"
                                                            tabindex="#{headerBean.tabIndex}"
                                                            accesskey="#{participantBundle.BILLING_INVOICE_MEDIA_AKEY}"
                                                            styleClass="required">
                                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel=" " itemValue=" " />
                                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Descriptive"
                                                                itemValue="Descriptive" />
                                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="CASS Tape" itemValue="CASS Tape" />
                                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Government Form"
                                                                itemValue="Government Form" />
                                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Literal" itemValue="Literal" />
                                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Tape" itemValue="Tape" />
                                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Email" itemValue="Email" />
                                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="FTP" itemValue="FTP" />
                                                            <f:converter converterId="EnumConverter"></f:converter>
                                                        </h:selectOneMenu> 
                                                    </cc:customTd>
                                                    <cc:customTd></cc:customTd>

                                                    <cc:customTd>
                                                        <h:selectOneMenu id="invoiceFrequency"
                                                            value="#{item.invoiceFrequency}"
                                                            title="#{participantBundle.INVOICE_FREQUENCY_TIP}"
                                                            tabindex="#{headerBean.tabIndex}" styleClass="required">
                                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel=" " itemValue=" " />
                                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Weekly" itemValue="Weekly" />
                                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bi-Monthly"
                                                                itemValue="Bi-Monthly" />
                                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Daily" itemValue="Daily" />
                                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Demand" itemValue="Demand" />
                                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Monthly" itemValue="Monthly" />
                                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="10 days" itemValue="10 days" />
                                                            <f:converter converterId="EnumConverter"></f:converter>
                                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                                                    </cc:customTd>

                                                    <cc:customTd></cc:customTd>

                                                    <cc:customTd>
                                                         <h:selectOneMenu id="invoiceSequence"
                                                            value="#{item.invoiceSequence}"
                                                            title="#{participantBundle.INVOICE_SEQUENCE_TIP}"
                                                            tabindex="#{headerBean.tabIndex}" styleClass="required">
                                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel=" " itemValue=" " />
                                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ascending Order"
                                                                itemValue="Ascending Order" />
                                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Double Space"
                                                                itemValue="Double Space" />
                                                            <f:converter converterId="EnumConverter"></f:converter>
                                                        </h:selectOneMenu> 
                                                    </cc:customTd>
                                                    <cc:customTd>
                                                        <h:inputText id="txtInvoiceLanguage"
                                                            value="#{item.invoiceLanguage}"
                                                            tabindex="#{headerBean.tabIndex}" size="3" maxlength="3"
                                                            styleClass="required"
                                                            title="#{participantBundle.INVOICE_LANGUAGE_TIP}" />
                                                    </cc:customTd>
                                                    <cc:customTd></cc:customTd>
                                                    <cc:customTd>
                                                        <h:inputText id="txtSite"
                                                            value="#{item.invoiceSite}"
                                                            tabindex="#{headerBean.tabIndex}" size="3" maxlength="3"
                                                            styleClass="required"
                                                            title="#{participantBundle.INVOICE_SITE_TIP}" />
                                                    </cc:customTd>
                                                    <cc:customTd></cc:customTd>
                                                    <cc:customTd>
                                                        <h:inputText id="txtBillingCurrency"
                                                            value="#{item.currency}"
                                                            tabindex="#{headerBean.tabIndex}" size="3" maxlength="3"
                                                            styleClass="required"
                                                            title="#{participantBundle.BILLING_CURRENCY_TIP}" />
                                                    </cc:customTd>
                                                    <cc:customTd></cc:customTd>
                                                    <cc:customTd>
                                                        <h:inputText id="txtInvoiceEmail"
                                                            style="vertical-align:top;"
                                                            value="#{item.invoiceEmail}"
                                                            size="45" maxlength="68" styleClass="optional"
                                                            title="#{participantBundle.DETAILS_EMAIL_TIP}" /></cc:customTd></cc:customTr></cc:customTable>
</a4j:repeat>
```

The problem is when I add a new row using the drop down and then set the value to the input box in the a4j:repeat component and submit form , the backing bean is set with with null value for all the fields.
Where as when i don't add any new row and save form the data is saved in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because every time you are adding new objects of  `aBillingPartsInfoDto` to the list `billingInfoDtos` and not set any values to the dto variables.

```
if(this.getBillingSize()<this.getMaxAirlineCodeAllowed()){
            aBillingPartsInfoDto= new BillingPartsInfoDto();

            /* Set values to dto variables here */

            billingInfoDtos.add(aBillingPartsInfoDto);
            this.setBillingSize(this.getBillingInfoDtos().size());
        }
```

Comment: my requirement is to add a new empty object which will have a set of UI fields. the user will enter the data into the input boxes. The data is entered by user on form submission is null. Where as when i dont add any new rows and enter values to the default first row present then on form submisiion i don lose any value.

Comment: I have edited the post to add the a4j:repeat contents